# WinRt C# null exception - object scope issue using IAsyncOperationWithProgress

Tags: c#, scope, windows-runtime, nullreferenceexception

I'm working in WinRt calling a WinRt Class Library from a Windows Store App using C# and SQLite... objects are returning null reference errors at unexpected times...

I'm trying to implement a logon service that checks to see if the current user is already logged in by checking if the data file exists, then checking if the user is the current user logged in...

The user can simply enter their ID and click a logon button. It creates a DataService object that wraps a SQLite database and is then "injected" into the UserStartupService.

The UserStartupService uses Dependency Injection, singleton and implements IDisposable.

Issue 1) if the user clicks the logon button a second time, the UserStartupService object constructor does not run and when internal objects are used they throw null reference errors even though it runs through the dispose method after it exits the using block, which forces me to deactivate the logon button, which is a kluge fix at best. A new user has to exit the program to log in as a new user. (The original code did not implement IAsyncOperationWithProgress, but that should not matter...)

Issue 2) I'm now trying to implement IAsyncOperationWithProgress to relay progress back to the UI and it gets a null reference error the instant it tries to use _dataFeedService on the line:

var json = await _dataFeedService.ValidateUser(userId);

Even though it runs the constructor at the top of the using statement as expected...

I think there is a scope/thread issue that I'm missing here. Maybe something obvious...

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
// logon button pressed...
private void LogOn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create database service for DI
    DataService _dataService = new DataService("MyData.sqlite");

    // using statement for scope control
    using (UserStartupService uss = UserStartupService.GetInstance(_dataService))
    {
        // progress bar...
        CurrentProgress.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;

        // create op and call...
        IAsyncOperationWithProgress<string, int> op;
        op = uss.SetUpUser(txtUserId.Text);

        op.Progress = (info, progress) =>
        {
            CurrentProgress.Value = progress;
        };

        op.Completed = (info, status) =>
        {
            var results = info.GetResults();
            // when completed...
            if (status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
            {
                txtMessage.Text = "Current user data already loaded...";
                CurrentProgress.Value = 100;
            } // if cancelled...
            else if (status == AsyncStatus.Canceled)
            {
                // Operation canceled - not implemented...
            }
        };
    }
    btnLogon.IsEnabled = false;
}


public sealed class UserStartupService : IDisposable
{
    #region properties

    // services
    private static DataService _dataService;
    private static DataFeedService _dataFeedService;
    private static SqliteService _sqlMAFService;
    private static SerialiseDeserialiseService _serializeService;

    private string _token = String.Empty;

    #endregion properties

    #region constructors with DI and singleton pattern

    // use this code to implement singleton patter...
    // private constructor = can't instance without GetInstance...
    private UserStartupService(DataService dataService)
    {
        // guard clause...
        if (dataService == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("DataService");
        }
        _dataService = dataService;
        _dataFeedService = new DataFeedService();
        _sqlMAFService = new SqliteService(_dataService);
        _serializeService = new SerialiseDeserialiseService();
    }

    // implement singleton
    public static UserStartupService GetInstance(DataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        return MyNestedSingletonClass.singleton;
    }

    class MyNestedSingletonClass
    {
        internal static readonly UserStartupService singleton = new UserStartupService(_dataService);

        static MyNestedSingletonClass() { }
    }

    #endregion constructors with DI and singleton pattern

    public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<string, int> SetUpUser(string userId)
    {
        return AsyncInfo.Run<string, int>((token, progress) =>
            Task.Run<string>(async () =>
            {
                progress.Report(1);

                try
                {
                    // validate user against server REST feed and get token
                    var json = await _dataFeedService.ValidateUser(userId);

                                                        // ... it never gets here due to _dataFeedService null exception
                    // ...more code ... never gets here...


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return ex.Message;
                }

                progress.Report(100);

                return "";
            }, token));
    }

    #region implement IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _serializeService = null;
        _sqlMAFService.Dispose();
        _sqlMAFService = null;
        _dataFeedService.Dispose();
        _dataFeedService = null;
        _dataService.CloseConnection();
        _dataService = null;
    }
    #endregion implement IDisposable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `using` block will dispose `uss` before it is done executing, so that's where your null reference exceptions are coming from (for both issues).

If `UserStartupService` is a singleton, and it could be used multiple times, then don't dispose it.

Also, I would recommend using `await` rather than callbacks (it's usually simpler), so something like this should work:

```
private async void LogOn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  btnLogon.IsEnabled = false;

  // Create database service for DI
  DataService _dataService = new DataService("MyData.sqlite");

  var uss = UserStartupService.GetInstance(_dataService);

  // progress bar...
  CurrentProgress.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;

  // create op and call...
  var op = uss.SetUpUser(txtUserId.Text)
      .AsTask(progress => { CurrentProgress.Value = progress; });
  var result = await op;

  txtMessage.Text = "Current user data already loaded...";
  CurrentProgress.Value = 100;

  btnLogon.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Good suggestion on the dispose. I'm implementing your suggestion to see how the rest of it goes. I'll let you know.